# Array weatherapi

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, api

I am building a weather dashboard, so Im using the Api from Weather API. I dont have problem with fetching the api but in the Response I am getting and array for the forecast days.

So, Im using React + TS. For that reason I need to declarate my useStates before to populating. I dont have problem Populating a simple interface but when i need to populate the array I dont know whit is his initial State.

```
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState<IForecast>({
    date: "",
    icon: "",
    maxC: "",
    minC: "",
  });
```

That is my interface, how i can say it that it recieved an array of that interface?

Comment: is `typeof variableName === IForecast` what you are looking for?

Comment: `const [forecast, setForecast] = useState<IForecast[]>([]);` is what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. so i have three objects with the info from the response. I named Forecast0, Forecast1, and Forecast2. 

How I add those Forecast0, Forecast1 and Forecast2 to the Array Forecast?
Thanks for your time

Comment: You don't add them to the existing array, you set a new one: `setForecast([Forecast0, Forecast1, Forecast2])`. Mutating existing state is not supported in React, and pretty well-covered in the offical docs. Also if you are addressing a particular person make sure to @ them in your comment, otherwise we don't get notified. It was actually lucky I stumbled across this again.

Comment: @JaredSmith Ohhh thanks. this works for me. I am learning TS for that reason sometimes I have problem with the types. Thanks for that and thanks for the recomendation about @. Have a nice day